# How can I create a resource list on Apigility?

Tags: rest, laminas-api-tools

So, I have a create method on Apigility to create a resoure which is basically a

```
POST /resources
{
  <fields go here>
}
```

... and I was wondering how can I also have the option to create a list of these resources.

From what I can see these are my options:

- replaceList: `PUT /resources`
- patchList: `PATCH /resources`

but I'm not sure which kind of payload I should send. Should I send an array of resources or an object with an array of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If you create a DbConnected Service, see this code https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility/blob/master/src/DbConnectedResource.php.</s>

This methods are not implemented by default.

If you create a code connected service, you can send any payload. The data will be parsed as a array to you make what you want.

I don't know the behavior of validation on these requests.

If you send a array of entities, the Apigility 1.0.4 will validate each entity [(see this link)](https://groups.google.com/a/zend.com/forum/#!msg/apigility-users/Ifamcj5Ai5E/lT_4e9P0jbkJ), maybe you have to write especific validators to each  HTTP METHOD, or relax the general validator [(see this link)](https://apigility.org/documentation/content-validation/advanced).

This link has some suggest to your payload https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/halprimer.

In your case I would use a array.

Comment: I ended up using an array, but had to disable the automatic validation on the POST method. ):

Comment: You can create a custom validation to POST, PATCH PUT OR DELETE, but I  dont't know how match the validation with replaceList or patchList https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-content-validation